# Why don't we reach the state directly in NgRx?

Tags: typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

currently I'm learning NgRx. So far I learned this:

- For changing the state, we dispatch so called actions
- An action is an object with an identifier and optionally with a payload
- This action doesn’t directly reach the store, instead it reaches a so called reducer
- The reducer is just a function: it gets the current state from the store and the action as an input
- In the reducer we can have a look at the action identifier and perform the change on the state accordingly (which we got as an argument) to update that state, in an immutable way (changing the copy)
- The reducer returns a new state, it returns a copy of the old state, and this state is forwarded to the app store
- This reduced state is then overwriting the old state

I can't really understand, why we don't directly change the state stored in the store? Why do we need this reducer and make the change on a copy of the state in the store and write it back?

For my another question here is a bit code:

```
import { Ingredient } from '../../shared/ingredient.model';
import * as ShoppingListActions from './shopping-list.actions';

const initialState = {
  ingredients: [new Ingredient('Apples', 5), new Ingredient('Tomatoes', 10)]
};

export function shoppingListReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: ShoppingListActions.AddIngredient
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        ingredients: [...state.ingredients, action.payload]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is a simple reducer. Here we create a new state by returning the old state and overriding the `ingredients`.

Is there a pattern to follow, how we have to return the new state or it depends on the state in the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For your first question as to why we do not directly change the state of your store. The answer is **immutability**

I think the key point that whole [action > reducer > store > selector] flow is **immutability**. It ensures the lack of any undesirable side effects and that your actions are predictable and repeatable.

This usually leads to improved performance and usually simpler programming and debugging.

As your application scales, the NGRX architecture will allow you to have a consistent and reliable state management.

2. Regarding pattern to follow, how we have to return the new state.

You just have to return a new state of the store. This helps to change to ensure a "new" value is always returned. Considering your reducer's state is an object, I think a "new" state helps refresh the value of your store and allows your application to know if there is a change made in the reducer.

A direct mutation of your state would not result in this refresh as described earlier.

Answer (score 0):

@wscttc's answer already mentions the immutability of the state and why this prevents unintended side effects.

However I wanted to mention another superior advantage, which are the pure functions that you use for the reducer. You know that these functions are the only part in your app that modify the state. These functions are usually super simple and they are also super simple to test. By the actions you can find the places where they are triggered easily.